# How to find which version of ui-router is used in Ionic 1 project?

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework, angular-ui-router

We hava a website that is built with AngularJS v1.5.6 and ui-router v1.0.0. We want to transfer this site to hybrid app and most logical solution was to use Ionic framework (at least that what we thought)

The problem we encountered was that ionic v1 came out in time when AngularJS did not have `component` method so we have to re-write code to old and messy `ng-controller` approach.

Also, we used ui-routers `$transitions.onStart({}, function(), {})` inside `app.run` method. We know that in Ionic there are `$ionicView.beforeEnter` equivalent for that however while these events are great for resolving data(transition to next page is smoother than using ui-routers `resolve`) this in not so good when trying to protect login pages.

So question basically is which version of ui-router is used in Ionic v1 framework? So that we could look up the correct docs and find the best solution.

Comment: Show package.json. To find answer it's good to know at least a release version of ionic.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, I checked my ionic1 app, and I have found that `"version": "0.2.18"` of `ui-router` was used. I hope it help

Comment: Thank you, now I know how to find ui-version for corresponding Ionic version. Have to say - old versions of ui-router with lot of good functionality missing,..